# How to Change the URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Also I want to hide the .php extension

My URL is:

```
www.mysite.com/Alumni/searchprofile?profile=maria_s
```

And I want to change it to:

```
www.mysite.com/Alumni/maria_s
```

Any clues please I need an ASAP answer?

Comment: Your question makes no sense, considering what you have and what you want to change it to are exactly the same things.

Comment: Anyone found difference between `www.mysite.com/Alumni/searchprofile?profile=maria_s` and `www.mysite.com/Alumni/searchprofile?profile=maria_s` ?

Comment: I am unable to spot the difference between the first and second url

Comment: Sorry guys i want

My URL is:

www.mysite.com/Alumni/searchprofile?profile=maria_s
And I want to change it to:

www.mysite.com/Alumni/maria_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

For more info visit: http://blog.theonlytutorials.com/remove-php-extension-url-htaccess/

Hope this will help..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Alumni/([^/]*)$ /Alumni/searchprofile?profile=$1

# Hide php extension.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: can u send me the full code , i want to hide the.php ext tooo